# VB the microsoft access database engine could not find the object

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm receiving the following run time error on VB (Excel 10) "the microsoft access database engine could not find the object". The "Database" is a defined named within a worksheet but it wont pick it up. Any ideas would be hugely appreciated!!

```
Sub ConnectDB()


If cnn.State <> adStateOpen Then

Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = "O:Children's Fund\APS 2014-15\Refrerral - Allocation Database.xlsx"

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strFileName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

End If

End Sub


Sub CopyData()

ConnectDB

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim CurrentID As Long
Dim vbResult As VbMsgBoxResult

rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [A2:M1000];", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    If Not rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveLast
    CurrentID = rst("RefNumber")
    CurrentID = CurrentID + 1
Else
    CurrentID = 1
End If

        Dim sql As String

        sql = "Insert into [Database] (refnumber, surname, FirstName, DOB, ReferrerEmail, PreferredSetting, MotherEmployment, FatherEmployment, OtherEmployment, Other1Employment, Attendance, Exclusions) values ('" & _
        CurrentID & "','" & [FormSurname] & "','" & [FormFirstName] & "','" & [FormDOB] & "','" & [FormEmail] & "','" & [FormPreferred] & "','" & [FormMother] & "','" & [FormFather] & "','" & [FormOther] & "','" & [FormOther1] & "','" & [FormAttendance] & "','" & [FormExclusions] & "')"



        cnn.Execute (sql)

        MsgBox "Record Saved to Database"

DisconnectDB

End Sub

Sub DisconnectDB()

If cnn.State <> adStateClosed Then

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End If


End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Sam

Comment: Where have you initialized `cnn` ?

Comment: What line throws the error?!?!?!